# Log http traffic network for third party analytic library for android apps

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase-analytics, charles-proxy

So currently i am using **chuck** http interceptor for seeing all my network call that are generated from my application, i also have some third party analytics sdk's which send some analytic event , so to log the request generated by those third party sdk i ended up using **charles proxy**.

I have also tried stetho but that also didn't help.

Is there something else other than charles which will allow me to log third party analytics request generated form my app?

Answer (score 1):

Many people talks about an alternative called [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler). I haven't tested it yet, but I think is centered in http requests, as Charles Proxy.

Also you can try [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), which logs all the traffic on your computer. It is probably a bit harder to configure and use but will work too.

Answer (score 1):

I think Charles is highly matured and stable so I'm not sure other apps could help resolving your issues :-? But if you're using macOS, I think https://proxyman.io/ would be worth trying. Not into Wireshark as it's a little bit hard to use :-?